# Loop device support on self compiled kernel doesn't work

Tags: kernel, mount, compiling, loop-device

I compiled 3.10 kernel, I checked that these configuration lines are not commented

```
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP_MIN_COUNT=8
```

When i'm trying to mount loop device I get this error

```
# mount -o loop /file.cpio /mnt
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /mnt failed: Invalid argument
# modprobe loop
modprobe: can't change directory to '/lib/modules' : No such file or directory
```

How to fix that? Thanks.

**Update**

I didn't do `make modules` `make modules_install`, I fixed that

now `modprobe loop` output is `modprobe: module 'loop' not found`

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. When you select 'y' in the kernel, the driver is built in, so there is no module. If you want a module, you would need to select 'm' for the kernel option.
2. You can't mount a cpio archive using loop. You can only mount files which contain filesystems. An .iso file, for example, contains the iso9660 filesystem. A SD card image might contain an ext3 filesystem, etc. The cpio is a compressed archive, not a filesystem per se